# force directed graph change color of all connected node on mouseover

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a force directed graph with different nodes, I want to change the color of the selected node and all the connected (neighbour) nodes when user does mouseover to it.

I am trying to do this..

```
function onMouseover(d){
  node.style("fill", function(o){
    var color = isConnected(d, o) ? 'red' : 'blue';
    return color;
  })
  force.resume();
}

function isConnected(d, o){
  return o.index === d,index || 
         (d.children && d.children.indexOf(o.index) !== -1) ||
         (o.children && o.children.indexOf(d.index) !== -1) ||
         (o.parents && o.parents.indexOf(d.index) !== -1) ||
         (d.parents && d.parents.indexOf(o.index) !== -1);
}
```

Can any one please help me here, or point me to some similar d3 graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo based on Mike Bostock’s [Force-Directed Graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) which changes the color of the hovered node and its direct connected nodes:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4062045/raw/5916d145c8c048a6e3086915a6be464467391c62/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.on("mouseover", function(d) {

    var connectedNodeIds = graph
      .links
      .filter(x => x.source.id == d.id || x.target.id == d.id)
      .map(x => x.source.id == d.id ? x.target.id : x.source.id);

    d3.select(".nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .attr("fill", function(c) {
        if (connectedNodeIds.indexOf(c.id) > -1 || c.id == d.id) return "red";
        else return color(c.group);
      });
  });

  node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select(".nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .attr("fill", function(c) { return color(c.group); });
  });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="350"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**During the mouseover**, the idea is to:

1. Retrieve the id of the hovered node,
2. From all links, get the ones whose either the source or the target is the id of this hovered node,
3. From these matching links, retrieve the associated node id connected to the hovered node,
4. Go through all nodes and change the color of those matching the previously found nodes.

this way:

```
node.on("mouseover", function(d) {

  var connectedNodeIds = graph
    .links
    .filter(x => x.source.id == d.id || x.target.id == d.id)
    .map(x => x.source.id == d.id ? x.target.id : x.source.id);

  d3.select(".nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .attr("fill", function(c) {
      if (connectedNodeIds.indexOf(c.id) > -1 || c.id == d.id) return "red";
      else return color(c.group);
    });
});
```

**During the mouseout**, we go through all nodes and set back the original color:

```
node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
  d3.select(".nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .attr("fill", function(c) { return color(c.group); });
});
```