# How do you highlight nodes, their connected nodes, and their connections when moused over in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter

I have [this fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rbb791/7rxbw0nj/29/) of a simple node-link diagram. I want to change colors of the node that is hovered over and its connected nodes. I also want the links themselves to become larger or bolder. I am basing my code off of an accepted answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175871/force-directed-graph-change-color-of-all-connected-node-on-mouseover). Here is the relevant block of code for the `mouseover()` function:

```
.on("mouseover", function (d) {
      var connectedNodes = data.links
        .filter((x) => x.source === d.name || x.target === d.name)
        .map((x) => (x.source === d.name ? x.target : x.source));

    //my function to highlight node and connected nodes. only highlights first node in map.
      d3.select(".node")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .attr("fill", function (c) {
          if (connectedNodes.indexOf(c.name) > -1 || c.name === d.name)
            return "red";
          else return "blue";
        });
      console.log(data.links);
      console.log(connectedNodes);
    })
```

The first problem is, the `.filter()` function returns an empty array when logged. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my guess, your filter function is missing an attribute.

```
.on("mouseover", function (d) {
  var connectedNodes = data.links
    .filter((x) => **x.source === d.name || x.target === d.name**)
```

I logged the `x.source` and I found that it is an object with one of the key `name`, so the object is not equal to a string, the return is empty.

Change `x.source` to `x.source.name` and `x.target` to `x.target.name` (same in the map function) and the return won't be empty.

**Highlight**

you used `d3.select(".node")`  so only one selection will return, since each node is grouped by a `g` element. Use `d3.selectAll(".node")`  instead.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
var connectedNodes = data.links
  .filter((x) => x.source.name === d.name || x.target.name === d.name)
  .map((x) => (x.source.name === d.name ? x.target.name : x.source.name));

//my function to highlight node and connected nodes. only highlights first node in map.
  d3.selectAll(".node") 
    .selectAll("circle")
    .attr("fill", function (c) {
      
      if (connectedNodes.indexOf(c.name) > -1 || c.name === d.name)
        return "red";
      else return "blue";
    });

})
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owapgchj/3/)